# PHP VCard Not importing/Generating

Tags: php, oop, vcf-vcard

I am working on a php Vcard facility in a site that works fine locally but not on a live server.
Locally I am essentially getting the contact details and writing them to a .vcf file on the server ie lewis_cains.vcf which might look like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:name;Full
FN:Full name
ORG:Company name
TITLE:Job title
END:VCARD
```

etc..

Then on the site I have a direct link to the .vcf file and this links/downloads into my address book perfectly when working locally.

However, I have pushed this onto a live server and it has been outputting a plain text file with the above content.
Upon some more research I modified things slightly and have made this method to handle it using a php header:

```
public static function load_vcard($team_slug){
    $vcard_file = BASE_URL.'vcards/'.$team_slug.'.vcf';
    header('Content-Type: text/vcard');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$team_slug.".vcf\";");
    readfile($vcard_file);
}
```

Now I'm in a position where it tries to download the file but when I click the link I am getting a 'no importable cards found' message.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this would locally and not live, and then why it doesn't seem to be reading the file correctly?

Many thanks for your help,
Lewis.

Comment: Have you tried checking if the file path is correct?
something like:
    if(readfile($vcard_file)){
    echo 'exists';
    }

Answer (score 0):

The way you are loading the vCard file may be the cause of the problem.  The vCard file exists on the server, right?  Yet, you appear to be using a URL to load the file, instead of a filesystem path.  Using a filesystem path may solve the problem:

```
public static function load_vcard($team_slug){
    $vcard_file = __DIR__.'/vcards/'.$team_slug.'.vcf';
    header('Content-Type: text/vcard');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$team_slug.".vcf\";");
    readfile($vcard_file);
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks very much for your help, I have just tried this. For some crazy reason this still isn't working. It can find the file fine, if I test it using file_get_contents() it shows me exactly what is in the file but when I try to download the vcard it fails! Very frustrating and really don't know where to go next with it. Thanks again anyway and please let me know if you have any other thoughts.

Comment: No problem. :D  Just a few more thoughts: A file on the production server may be out of sync with your local installation, which is indirectly causing this issue.   Maybe if you do a clean deploy to the live server this issue will go away.  Also, is any data being written to the response before this method is called?  Maybe a debug-related "echo" wormed its way into the live server. Headers have to be set *before* anything is written to the response.